# Why claws mail can receive email instead of mail command?

Tags: email, mailx

```
mail -f /var/mail/debian9
/var/mail/debian9: 0 messages
```

When `mail -f /var/mail/debian9` executing ,the claws mail application is in off status.

Now open the /var/mail/debian9 with claws mail.

```
sudo apt-get install -y claws-mail
```

claws mail is here [claws mail](http://www.claws-mail.org)

[image: open with claws mail]

Claws-mail say there 665 total 655  unread.
Why `mail -f /var/mail/debian9` display none of email?

Answer (score 0):

claws-mail will create a directory ,for example in my pc, /home/debian9/Mail.

```
ls -al  /home/debian9/Mail 
total 40
drwx------  7 debian9 debian9  4096 Apr 25 17:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 65 debian9 debian9  4096 Apr 25 17:59 ..
drwx------  2 debian9 debian9  4096 Apr 24 11:08 draft
drwx------  2 debian9 debian9 16384 Apr 25 17:39 inbox
-rw-r--r--  1 debian9 debian9     0 Apr 25 17:50 .mh_sequences
drwx------  2 debian9 debian9  4096 Apr 24 11:08 queue
drwx------  2 debian9 debian9  4096 Apr 24 10:47 sent
drwx------  2 debian9 debian9  4096 Apr 24 11:45 trash
```

claws-mail find some email in my /var/mail and /var/spool/mail and change the format ,saved them in .mh_sequences.
The displayed email are all in .mh_sequences.